# Java Stream - NullPointExeption when filter list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to filter from the list objects that field `isActive` have either set to N or null. Unfortunately, I get `NullPointerException` in method filter and I don't know what is wrong?

Code:

```
...
return dictionary.getAllPermissions().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(z->"N".equals(z.getIsActive().toString()) || z.getIsActive().equals(null)) //field isActive is Character
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the ordering wrong, it should be:

```
.filter(z -> z.getIsActive() == null || "N".equals(z.getIsActive().toString()))
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that .toString() throws a NullPointExeption

Comment: @xampo Is not that `toString` throws NPE, the fact that you're invoking it on `null` does

Answer (score 3):

You should invert the checks here:

```
.filter(z->"N".equals(z.getIsActive().toString()) || z.getIsActive().equals(null))
```

to

```
.filter(z-> z.getIsActive() == null || "N".equals(z.getIsActive().toString()))
```

The idea is to first make sure that the value `z.getIsActive()` is not null before you can actually invoke the `tostring()` method to it.

Answer (score 2):

`z.getIsActive().toString()` throws a NullPointExeption when `isActive` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You said "field 'isActive' have either set to N or null", so if it's null all your z.getIsActive are null, so you need to check z.getIsActive==null